# jQuery click() not working in a Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey script

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I am having issues triggering a jQuery click through Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey...

```
jQuery('button').each(function() {
    jQuery(this).css('background', 'red');
    jQuery(this).click();
    location.assign("javascript:jQuery(this).click();void(0)");
}​
```

As you can see I've even tried the [location.assign hack](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Location_hack) but nothing will work, no errors in the console either.

Funny thing is that yes, the background colour does change to red so I am assuming it's something in the way `.click()` works that is different from other jQuery methods.

Comment: What about `jQUery(this).trigger('click');`?

Comment: Just tried `unsafeWindow.jQuery(this).click();` as well.

Comment: @JamWaffles yes I've tried that too.

Comment: Ah fair enough. I read somewhere that `trigger()` sometimes works where `click()` doesn't.

Comment: unsafeWindow only works in FF and maybe IE as far as I remember, chrome doesn't accept it. Also, I'd suggest the script injection hack instead of the location one.

Comment: Also keep in mind that greasemonkey runs in a sandbox, so you can't assign DOM elements to a function inside your greasemonkey script (unless you inject it through a hack). Do you have the JQuery library included in the html page you're running that script or inside your script?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté it's included in the script. No issues with running jQuery, I can change colours. Something to do with `.click()` and `.each` that's making it harder to break out of the sandbox.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

jQuery's `.click()` is just a shortcut for jQuery's `.trigger()` and from the [Docs](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=trigger):

> Any event handlers attached with .bind() or one of its shortcut methods are triggered when the corresponding event occurs. They can be fired manually, however, with the .trigger() method.

This means that event-handlers, that are not set by jQuery, cannot always be triggered by `.click()` (or `.trigger()`).

To get around this, send actual mouse events:

```
jQuery ('button').each ( function () {
    jQuery (this).css ('background', 'red');

    var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
    this.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}
```

---

Note that in some rare cases, the page will actually work off a combination of events, not the `click`, and that theoretically, pages can discriminate against ***any*** artificially produced event (though I've yet to see that in the wild).
If that is the case here, link to the target page so that we can make workaround(s).

Comment: @FabianoLothor, Every programmer's fantasy... Glad to help!

Comment: In this question is a page on which it doesn't seem to work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41088878/button-click-doesnt-work-in-greasemonkey-tampermonkey-script-already-tried-sta

Comment: @Thomas, see my answer there.