# Greasemonkey not seeing changes made to DOM on Facebook

Tags: greasemonkey

I'm using my GM script to link a number of pages. If I create a script that contains just the following code: (I'm using jQuery btw)

```
$(".rfloat.uiButton").trigger('click');
```

It will like the number of pages in the list. But there is a button at the bottom that says "See More Results". These are being loaded by Ajax. So, I updated my script to listen for elements being attatched to the DOM, like so:

```
$("#pagelet_search_results_objects").bind("DOMSubtreeModified",HandleDOM_ChangeWithDelay);

var zGbl_DOM_ChangeTimer = null;

function HandleDOM_ChangeWithDelay (zEvent) {
    if (typeof zGbl_DOM_ChangeTimer == "number") {
        clearTimeout (zGbl_DOM_ChangeTimer);
        zGbl_DOM_ChangeTimer = '';
    }
    zGbl_DOM_ChangeTimer = setTimeout (HandleDOM_Change, 333);
}

function HandleDOM_Change () {
    alert("New content loaded"); // This fires once
    $("a.rfloat.uiButton").trigger('click');
}
```

The alert fires after I click the "See More Results" and the new page results are added to the DOM. But the click trigger won't fire. It's as if GM is not seeing the changes that have been applied to the DOM.

Why is this?

**Edit:**

When doing

```
alert($("a.rfloat.uiButton").length);
```

It's displaying the updated number, but still not clicking them.

Answer (score 0):

What's the error console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>) say?

So far, I don't see any Facebook pages that match `$("a.rfloat.uiButton")`. Link to one.

It's quite possibly that FB uses different event handling for the added links, and [jQuery's `.trigger()` only operates on a small-subset of events.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10423628/331508)

Try:

```
jQuery ('a.rfloat.uiButton').each ( function () {
    var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
    this.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}
```

---

It's also possible that the new links do not even fire off of clicks.  See ["Choosing and activating the right controls on an AJAX-driven site"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15052467/331508).

---

Running `$("a.rfloat.uiButton").trigger('click');` more than once would reclick the earlier links.  This *might* cause problems.