# GreaseMonkey + Youtube + .click()

Tags: javascript, youtube, click, greasemonkey

Goal: I load a YouTube playlist then GreaseMonkey `click()`s the "shuffle playlist" button.

I can run these two lines straight in my console and it works perfectly:

```
var shuffleBtn = document.querySelector(".yt-uix-button.shuffle-playlist");
shuffleBtn.click();
```

However, when I tried to move it into GreaseMonkday, it no longer works.
The `console.log`'s in the code below *do run*-- and the (commented out) `remove()` works, but the `click()` will *not* trigger.  I've also tried the [method outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10423426/jquery-click-not-working-in-a-greasemonkey-tampermonkey-script), sans the jQuery bits, but no luck either.

What am I missing?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        YouTube - Randomize Playlist
// @namespace   ytplaylistrandom
// @include     https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yyDUC1LUXSU&list=PLh6vppUwmWEMdp04u-tYABoDmgn9AX12n
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

window.onload = function () {
    var shuffleBtn = document.querySelector(".yt-uix-button.shuffle-playlist");
    if( shuffleBtn ){
      console.log('exists');
      shuffleBtn.click();
      //shuffleBtn.remove();
      console.log('end');
    }else {
      console.log('nobutton');
    }
}
```

Comment: I’ve tested it a bit… it should actually work, because programmatic clicking isn’t blocked in GreaseMonkey (I’ve done it plenty of times). I thought, maybe the button wasn’t properly initialized, but even with a delayed execution via `setTimeout` it didn’t seem to work.

Comment: It seems that when the user script executes, the shuffle button “loses” one of its two `click` event listeners: [there are two event listeners without the script](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1vsZF.png), but [only one event listener _with_ the script](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YXgu5.png).

Comment: Yeah, I've tried it with a `setTimeout` as well-- and `.trigger('click')`-- and tried the whole thing *with* jQuery...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it:

Use `window.addEventListener("load", function(){`…`})` instead of `window.onload = function(){`…`}`.

It seems that the `window` already has an `onload` function which initializes the functionality of the shuffle button and the script is *overriding* it.

Comment: That worked, thanks!  To be clear, I still had to wrap it in a `setTimeout`

Comment: @frogg3862 That’s really weird… it worked for me without that.

Comment: I also added `click()`s to `.toggle-loop` to make the playlist loop-- and `.ytp-next-button` to move on to the next song (initiating "randomization")